# About usage of wait_event_interruptible() - can the wake condition be missed?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Have a look at the code skeleton below (I modified [this](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-2) LDD3 code)

```
static ssize_t scull_p_read(struct file * filp, char __user * buf, size_t count,
    loff_t * f_pos) {
    SOME UNIMPORTANT CODE
    DOWN() /* semaphore */
    while (!COND_DATA_EXISTS) { /* nothing to read */
        UP() /* release the lock */
        wait_event_interruptible(SLEEP_QUEUE, COND_DATA_EXISTS);
        DOWN()
    }
    REST OF FUNCTION
}
```

I have a question about the usage of wait_event_interruptible() by this process (say process 1). What if the:

```
wake_up_interruptible(&SLEEP_QUEUE);
```

call from another process (say, process 2) which tells the kernel to wake up this process happens between the UP() and the call to wait_event_interruptible() in process 1? Wouldn't process 1 sleep for ever?

My initial answer to this question was that wait_event_interruptible() would check the condition COND_DATA_EXISTS before sleeping. Okay, now what if the wake_up_interruptible() from process 2 happens between the check of COND_DATA_EXISTS and process 1 sleeping **inside** wake_up_interruptible() in process 1?

Comment: Below in the book there is `Advance Sleeping` section. If you read it, you will find that condition is checked *after* `prepate_wait()` macro call, which sets process's state to `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`. Any `wake_up` call executed *after* this macro will set the process's state to `TASK_RUNNING`. `schedule()` called for process in running state does nothing (doesn't place process to sleep).